# Streamwriter is truncating Excel export data in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, excel, filestream

I am writing an Excel sheet using `streamwriter` and file stream it is working fine for small data but for large Excel files its truncating data. Here is my code:

```
'Increment unlimited
Using (objStreamWriter)
   For Each info As DataFileInfo In list
      If ((Not vendor.ExportByDivision And Not vendor.ExportBySubDivision) Or ((vendor.ExportByDivision And prevDivisionID = info.DivisionID) Or blnFirstRecord) Or ((vendor.ExportBySubDivision And prevSubDivisionID = info.SubDivisionID) Or blnFirstRecord)) Then
         objStreamWriter.WriteLine(InsertExportInfo(companyID, info, delimiter, vendor.DetailInvoiceExport))
         blnFirstRe cord = False
      Else 
         FileNumber = FileNumber + 1
         objStreamWriter.Close()
         objFileStream.Close()
         fileName = String.Format("{0}\{1}_{2}.{3}", Me.TempPath, vendor.ID, FileNumber, CType(vendor.DataExportType, VendorInfo.VendorDataExportType).ToString().ToLower())
         objFileStream = New FileStream(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write)
         'If the company contains unicode text
         If IsUnicodeCompany(companyID) Then
            objStreamWriter = New StreamWriter(objFileStream, System.Text.Encoding.Unicode)
         Else
            objStreamWriter = New StreamWriter(objFileStream)
         End If
         If vendor.DataExportType = VendorInfo.VendorDataExportType.XLS Then
             If vendor.DetailInvoiceExport = True Then
               objStreamWriter.WriteLine(String.Format(Me.GetDataExcelExportDetailHeader(companyID), delimiter))
             Else
               objStreamWriter.WriteLine(String.Format(Me.GetDataExcelExportHeader(companyID), delimiter))
             End If
         End If
         objStreamWriter.WriteLine(InsertExportInfo(companyID, info, delimiter, vendor.DetailInvoiceExport))
      End If
      prevDivisionID = info.DivisionID
      prevSubDivisionID = info.SubDivisionID
      objStreamWriter.Flush()
      objFileStream.Flush()
   Next
End Using
objStreamWriter.Close()
objFileStream.Close()
```

Comment: What do you mean with large data? Excel 2003 has a limit of 65,536 rows. Could that be the issue?

Comment: No its not issue with no of rows it is because data string containing double quotes e.g. "Rescheduled from 4.17.13'. Good product, members like the price